# How i can hide slot in angular?

Tags: angular

I have two case in Angluar. At first i have a slot ng-content but it can be empty.  At second, that slot can be empty, and i need to hide parent block if it is.

Im try to write ng-if, but thats not work

```
 <div class="content-block" *ng-If="ng-content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
 </div>
```

How i can do that?

```
<r-checkbox>Content <a href=''>link</a></r-checkbox>
```

Comment: ```*ng-If``` Directive is not correct. ```*ngIf``` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ng-content for dynamic content, for creating re-usable components and passing data from the parent component to the child components.

To conditionally show/hide content you should use the `*ngIf="condition"`, in your case you set 'ng-content' as the condition which is not defined.

```
 <div class="content-block" *ngIf="condition">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
 </div>
```

Then in your component:

```
const condition = true;
```